# Retrieve POST request body in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to POST soap xml request to codeigniter method. But it is not receiving the request xml. Everything looks ok but nothing works.
Tried all the commented code one by one but no luck

```
function index()
{
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
  {
   //echo "Dude! This is cool."; Works Fine!
   //echo $this->input->get_post();
   //echo $this->input->post();
   //echo $this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);

   print_r($_POST);
  } else {
        echo "Dude! This is not cool.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
function index()
{
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
   $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
   echo $data;

  } else {
        echo "Dude! This is not cool.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the input class creating a {subclass_prefix}_Input.php file in /application/core/